# The number of items in this list is approaching the list view threshold, which is 5000 items.

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-server, document-library, sharepoint-on-prem, list-view-threshold

I am working on sharepoint document library inside sharepoint on-premises 2013. the document library contain around 3800 files and folders. so when i went to the library setting, i got this warning message:-

[image]

so my question is how i can allow the document library to have more than 5,000 items? as in our case we store our projects documents inside this library, so it should allow use to have more than 5,000 items. is this is possible to increase the threshold? as if we can increase the threshold, then will it have any drawbacks ?
Regards

Answer (score 2):

You can increase the List view threshold setting by going to central admin.

- `Open Central admin -> Application Management -> Manage Web Applications`
- `Select Web applications -> Now from ribbon...Click on General Settings -> Resource throttling.`[image]
- Now change the settings as per your requirements: [image]

Link: [SharePoint 2013: List View Threshold](http://stevemannspath.blogspot.com/2013/05/sharepoint-2013-list-view-threshold.html)

Impact will be depending upon your infrastructure i.e.

- Number of Users
- List items
- Number of Servers
- Network

**Warning:** Changing the List View Threshold (LVT) is not recommended if you have other users, as larger values will degrade performance. Creating too large a value can cause high latency or failures for users, or potentially bring down a server.

[Manage large lists and libraries in SharePoint](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Manage-large-lists-and-libraries-in-SharePoint-B8588DAE-9387-48C2-9248-C24122F07C59#__bkmkchangelimit)

Comment: thanks for the reply. but seems the threshold of 5,000 does not mean that the document library can only hold 5,000 items, it means that the list view will only show max of 5,000 item.. is this correct? if this is the case then can i control which 5,000 items will be shown, for example can i say that the last 5,000 modified folders to be shown inside the list views? second question, let say my list will have 200,000 items then how i can view all those items (assuming that i will keep the current threshold of 5,000 as is)? can u adivce on my 2 points

Comment: That's correct, 5000 limit for views not lib/list. Yes you can control it by using filter option inside view settings, link k shared have information about it.

Comment: this topic is really confusing ,, now i find some articles which suggest to create index columns inside the list for all the sort & filter columns we use inside the list views, and they mentioned that doing so will allow the list view to show all the items (not just 5,000) ?? so is this correct? for example inside my current document library, i have a single list view which do not have filer (as it shows all items) and it sort the items based on the Modified date.. so if i create an index on the modified date my problem will be solved?

Comment: Index column is one of the options, if you able to create it then yes you can get required results

Comment: but let say i define to sort the list views items based on the "Modified" column and i created an Index on the "Modified" column,, then will the list view be able to show more than 5,000 items ?? if the answer is yes, then what is the magic of using index column in this case..

Answer (score 2):

Using PowerShell, you can also disable list throttling on a per-list basis rather than increasing the limit for all lists in a web application. The following shows the commands required:

> $web = Get-SPWeb http://urltoweb
>
> $list = $web.Lists["MyList"]
>
> $list.EnableThrottling = $false
>
> $list.Update()

While this can still have an effect on the farm as a whole if the list gets very large and/or lots of people are using it to retrieve many items, this only impacts a single list rather than all lists in a web application.

Comment: thanks for the reply.. so let say i disable Throttling on the list, and i found that this will cause problems inside our sharepoint server,, so can i enable it back? or this is a one time task that can not be reversed in the future?

Comment: You can just use the same commands with '$list.EnableThrottling = $true' instead to re-enable throttling whenever you want to.

Comment: i mean this is flexible process ... so i can test disabling the threshold and if i find that it will cause problems i can re-enable it again ?

Comment: Absolutely. If you're worried about it, pre-prepare your disable and re-enable scripts in advance so you just have to run them.